# how fill gridview in foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I fill a GridView in foreach because this code bring last row just not all.

```
foreach (int i in userdetails)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("*****");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("********=" + i, con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    gvSelected.Visible = true;
    gvSelected.DataSource = ds;
    gvSelected.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to do something more like this. Only get the data in the loop.
Notice I also used a SqlParameter which is important to prevent SQL Injection and avoid syntax errors.

```
   SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("*****");
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("********=@id", con);
   SqlParameter parId = new SqlParameter("@id", SqlDbType.Int);
   cmd.Parameters.Add(parId);
   SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
   DataSet ds = new DataSet();  

  foreach (int i in userdetails)
  {
      parId.Value = i;
      da.Fill(ds);       
  }

    gvSelected.Visible = true;
    gvSelected.DataSource = ds;
    gvSelected.DataBind();
```

Of course you should consider trying to send all ids at once if possible. You would need something like a Table Valued parameter for that.